# How to make fmt.Scanln() read into a slice of integers

Tags: go

I have a line containing 3 numbers that I want to read from stdin with fmt.Scanln() but this code won't work:

```
X := make([]int, 3)
fmt.Scanln(X...)
fmt.Printf("%v\n", X)
```

I get this error message:

```
cannot use X (type []int) as type []interface {} in function argument
```

I don't get it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func intScanln(n int) ([]int, error) {
    x := make([]int, n)
    y := make([]interface{}, len(x))
    for i := range x {
        y[i] = &x[i]
    }
    n, err := fmt.Scanln(y...)
    x = x[:n]
    return x, err
}

func main() {
    x, err := intScanln(3)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", x)
}
```

Input:

```
1 2 3
```

Output:

```
[1 2 3]
```

Comment: why doesn't this result in the output `[3, 3, 3]`? `x` would be intialized with `0` which all points to the same address when I tested in a `main` func.

Comment: I see, the address of `&x[i]` is unique but if iterating with `for i, v := range x { ...}`, the address of `v` is not unique.

Comment: what if instead of a length of 3 my input is not static?. i.e. Sometimes ```[1]``` and sometimes ```[1,2,3,4,5]```

Answer (score 13):

Idiomatic Go would be:

```
func read(n int) ([]int, error) {
  in := make([]int, n)
  for i := range in {
    _, err := fmt.Scan(&in[i])
    if err != nil {
       return in[:i], err
    }
  }
  return in, nil
}
```

`interface{}` means nothing. Please don't use it if you don't have to.

Answer (score 1):

I think the the correct version should be

```
X := make([]int, 3)
fmt.Scanln(&X[0], &X[1], &X[2])
fmt.Printf("%v\n", X)
```

Comment: Actually I have a bunch of lines to process and they're not all the same length, some have hundreds of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This error message occurs b/c there's no reasonable way to convert `[]int` to `[]interface{}`. Note, this is in reference to a slice. So the syntax your using is correct, but `fmt.Scanln` expects `[]interface{}`. This has implications outside of pkg `fmt`.

The reason I've seen given for this is due to Go giving you control over memory layout so it currently has no reasonable way to do the slice conversion. This means you'll need to do the conversion manually before passing it to a function expecting the slice of a given type. For example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    x := make([]int, 3)
    y := make([]interface{}, 3)
    y[0] = x[0]
    y[1] = x[1]
    y[2] = x[2]

    fmt.Println(y...)
}
```

Or something a little more general:

```
    x := make([]int, 3)
    y := make([]interface{}, len(x))
    for i, v := range x {
        y[i] = v
    }

    fmt.Println(y...)
```

Regarding your specific issue, see the following:

```
    x := make([]*int, 3)
    for i := range x {
        x[i] = new(int)
    }

    y := make([]interface{}, 3)

    for i, v := range x {
        y[i] = v
    }

    if _, err := fmt.Scanln(y...); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Scanln err: ", err)
    }

    for _, v := range y {
        val := v.(*int)
        fmt.Println(*val)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't get the error anymore but when I print, I get zeros, I guess because fmt.Scanln() expects references. I tried fmt.Scanln(&y...), to no avail. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I saw in a comment you said the lines can have different lengths. In that case
you can implement your own `fmt.Scanner`:

```
package main

import (
   "bytes"
   "fmt"
   "io"
)

type slice struct {
   tok []int
}

func (s *slice) Scan(state fmt.ScanState, verb rune) error {
   tok, err := state.Token(false, func(r rune) bool { return r != '\n' })
   if err != nil { return err }
   if _, _, err := state.ReadRune(); err != nil {
      if len(tok) == 0 {
         panic(err)
      }
   }
   b := bytes.NewReader(tok)
   for {
      var d int
      _, err := fmt.Fscan(b, &d)
      if err != nil {
          if err == io.EOF {break}
          return err
      }
      s.tok = append(s.tok, d)
   }
   return nil
}

func main() {
   var s slice
   fmt.Scan(&s)
   fmt.Println(s.tok)
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/fmt#Scanner